# Terrible performance on UWP DataGrid

Tags: uwp, datagrid

I'm looking for a good control to display tabular data in a UWP.  I'm getting pretty good performance with ListView and static headers, under a second to display 500 records.

So then I take UWP DataGrid out for a spin.  If I use AutoGenerateColumns, I get OK performance (roughly 4-5 seconds), but if I turn that feature off and use some basic DataGridTextColumns, the performance for the same set is horrible at roughly 30 seconds for just three columns:

```
<controls:DataGrid AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
                   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                   ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items.View}">
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Percent, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatter}, ConverterParameter=\{0:0.0%\}}"
                                     Header="Weight"
                                     Width="96"/>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SecurityName}"
                                     Header="Weight"
                                     Width="200"/>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Symbol}"
                                     Header="Symbol"
                                     Width="88"/>
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

It looks to me like the control is no longer virtualizing, but I can't find any controls to enable/disable virtualization.  The documentation for this control is really limited.  Has anyone got any practical experience with this control?  Any idea who the Auto Column feature works faster than the explicit column declaration?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Teleriks RadDataGrid for UWP as I know for sure it supports virtualization. They went open source, so it should be free to use!